# Autodesk Forge - Absolute coordinates

Tags: autodesk-forge

from the Forge viewer is it possible to retrieve the absolute coordinates of the objects?

With the following code I was able to obtain the relative coordinates of the selected object:

```
const viewer = NOP_VIEWER;
const dbId = NOP_VIEWER.getSelection()[0];
const selSet = viewer.getSelection();
const targetElem = selSet[0];
const model = viewer.model;
const instanceTree = model.getData().instanceTree;
const fragList = model.getFragmentList();

let bounds = new THREE.Box3();

instanceTree.enumNodeFragments( dbId, ( fragId ) => {
    let box = new THREE.Box3();
    fragList.getWorldBounds( fragId, box );
    bounds.union( box );
}, true );

const position = bounds.center();
```

With the getAecModelData method I was able to retrieve the refPointTransformation:

[image]

What do the values ​​in this array refer to?

TIA
Alder

Comment: Please don't add images, they are a pain to read. Use text.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you mean by absolute coordinates but if we're talking about geolocation, note that there's actually a Geolocation extension for the viewer:

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v6/reference/Extensions/GeolocationExtension

The extension leverages the `refPointTransformation` in AEC Model Data, letting you transform lat/long (WGS84) coordinates to viewer coordinates and vice versa.

Here's a related blog post that might also help: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/mini-map-geolocation-extension.